# What does upgrading a Spike-O-Pult monkey's pierce do?

Tags: bloons-td-5

When you upgrade a Dart Monkey into a Spike-O-Pult, the description is:

> Converts the Dart Monkey into a Spike-O-Pult, a powerful tower that hurls a large spiked ball instead of darts. Good range, but slower attack speed.Each ball can pop 18 bloons.

So the dart monkey goes from popping 1 balloon (2,0 upgrades) to 18 (3,0 udgrades).

However, what happens when you upgrade on the other path, where it says the Dart Monkey can now pop 2 or 3 balloons?  Does it add to the 18? Or is it useless as one upgrade pops 3 and the other pops 18?

Comment: I'm pretty sure they would just add to the 18. I can't imagine they'd actually make it useless.

Comment: IIRC, the piercing also helps against lead balloon's armor

Comment: Piercing and/or Armour Penetration have always been linked in games, for as long as I can remember. I'd imagine (having not played), that as @JamesCW has said, it would help defeat heavier, more protected units, quicker.

Comment: None of that extra piercing gets through lead though, unless you upgrade the Spike-O-Pult to the Juggernaut, so nope that doesnt work :/  I wanted to know if anyone actually knew the answer, I agree with all these comments that it should be useful, or else why spend the money, however I can't find any facts showing yes or know, so I'd like to know if I can save the money by not buying the upgrades.

Comment: You are correct, I must have been thinking of the Juggernaut upgrade.
I think the answer to your actual question lies in rate of fire and area of fire. The spike can pop 18 balloons, but only if they are in a straight line, and it fires more slowly than the other upgrade path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 0/1 and 0/2 upgrades add to the total giving the Spike-O-Pult 21 if you have it upgraded to 3/2 just like the add to the total of the 4/0 upgrade [Juggernaut](http://bloons.wikia.com/wiki/Juggernaut#Trivia) changing it from 100 to 103.

The extra 3 shots many not be noticeable especially if you are planning on immediately upgrading to the Juggernaut where the base popping power is 100 so it may make sense not to those upgrades and use the extra cash elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The catapult increases the number of bloons you can pop. The sharper shots increases the number of layers you can pop per bloon.